# Compute squared length of flipped edge from squared lengths of edges of adjacent triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

For two adjacent triangles, where $a, b, c$ and $a, d, e$ are the respective *squared* edge lengths of the triangles' edges. ($a$ is the squared length of the common edge). I have the following method (C++) for computing the squared length of the common edge after an edge flip:

```
auto cosGamma = (a + b - c) / (sqrt(a * b) * 2.0f);
auto cosDelta = (a + e - d) / (sqrt(a * e) * 2.0f);

auto sinGamma = sqrt(1.0f - cosGamma * cosGamma);
auto sinDelta = sqrt(1.0f - cosDelta * cosDelta);

auto cosAlpha = cosGamma * cosDelta - sinGamma * sinDelta;
return b + e - sqrt(b * e) * 2.0f * cosAlpha;
```

This method is based on the law of cosines and trigonometric addition formulas.

My question: Is there method for computing the squared length of the flipped edge of arbitrary adjacent triangles **that does not involve a square root computation**, and only uses squared edge lengths as input? Notably, the coordinates of the triangles' vertices are not known.

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you have two triangles $ABC$ and $ABD$ with a common side $AB$, and $C$ and $D$ on opposite sides of $AB$. You're letting, say, $AB^2 = a, AD^2 = b, BD^2 = c, AC^2 = d, BC^2 = e$. After that, you do an "edge flip," but I don't know what this means.

Comment: An edge flip flips the inner edge to CD, so the result is two triangles ADC and BCD. I'd like to know whether it is possible to compute the squared length of CD without evaluating a square root and using only squared edge lengths as input.

Answer (score 1):

I will restate the problem before giving the answer.

Four points $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are given in the plane (corresponding respectively to $A, B, C, D$ in the comments above).

There are six distances in all between the four points: $d_{12}, d_{13}, d_{14}, d_{23}, d_{24}, d_{34}$. We give names to the squares of the six distances as follows: $a = d_{12}^2, b = d_{14}^2, c = d_{24}^2, d = d_{13}^2, e = d_{23}^2, f = d_{34}^2$.

You want to find an expression for $f$ in terms of $a, b, c, d, e$. In essence, you want the relation between the lengths of the sides and the diagonals of a general plane quadrilateral.

This relation is given by equation $(10)$ in [this reference,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadrilateral.html) which I won't reproduce here. This relation can also be expressed by setting $V = 0$ in the Cayley-Venger determinant, $(11)$ of the same reference. (The Cayley-Venger determinant gives the square of the volume of a tetrahedron in terms of its six edges. This volume is zero since the vertices are assumed coplanar in your case.)

In summary, you will need to solve a quadratic equation to find $f$ in terms of $a, b, c, d, e$. The larger solution corresponds to the case in which $A_3$ and $A_4$ are on opposite sides of $A_1 A_2$, and the smaller solution for $f$ occurs when they are on the same side.

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I need. However, when solving the quadratic equation I still require a square root evaluation. Can we get rid of this one as well?

Comment: No, this is impossible. For example, let $A = (0,0), B = (1,0), C = (0,\sqrt{2}), D = (0,-\sqrt{3})$. Then $a, b, c, d, e$ are all integers, but $f = 5 + 2\sqrt{6}$ is not a rational number.